# Is it true that a person can only become Vaikhanasa by birth and not by Samskara?

Tags: pancharatra, agamas, vaikhanasa

To follow Vaikhanasa one must belong to the family lineage of Vaikhanasa tradition unlike the pancha ratra in which anyone can adopt it by deeksha. 
is this notion true ?

If so then is it not discrimination?

Comment: Yes, it is true. That's why they call themselves Garbha Vaishnavas; they think Vishnu initiates them in the womb.  See my answer here for more details: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14516/36

Comment: Why is it a discrimination? They consider it as a privilege. The custom is bit strange.

Comment: @SreeCharan That's why vaikhasa Vaishnavas are negligible in population.